# Button Inside DataTable Unable To Click After Ajax Reload

Tags: javascript, datatable, symfony4

I have a datable that each rows have two buttons "Cancel" and "Update". 
When the page starts loaded, i can click both of the cancel and update buttons. But after call ajax and add rows into a datatable, I am unable to click "Cancel" and "Update". Below screenshot is the result after I ajax call and try to click "update" button.

[image]

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
import 'semantic-ui-sass';
import 'datatables.net-se';
import {initReportDateTime, generateCSV} from "./helper";
import moment from 'moment';

//routing
const routes = require('../../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js';
import {cancelBooking} from "../utility/api";

Routing.setRoutingData(routes);


//dictionary variable for later use
let csvData ;
let totalNumOfDays =0;
let totalNumOfSales =0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    let postData = {
        startDate: null,
        endDate  : null,
        companies: null
    }

    drawTable(postData);

    initReportDateTime("#reportDateRange");

    $("#downloadCsv").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (csvData !== null && csvData !==''){
            generateCSV(csvData,"Sales_Report",totalNumOfSales.toFixed(2),totalNumOfDays);
        }
    });

    $("#report_form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let dateRange = $("#reportDateRange").val();
        let companies = $("#report_company").val();
        let status = $("#report_status").val();
        let splitDate = dateRange.split(" ");

        let startDate   = splitDate[0];
        let endDate     = splitDate[2];

        debugger;

        postData = {
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate  : endDate,
            companies: companies,
            status   : status
        }

        $('#salesTable').DataTable().destroy();

        //redraw table
        drawTable(postData);
    })

    $("#deleteReason").on('keypress',function () {
        ( $(this).val()  !== '') ?
            $(this).parent().removeClass('error') : null;

    })
});

export default function drawTable(postdata){
        let salesTable =$('#salesTable').DataTable( {
            "paging":   true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info":     false,
            "responsive": true,
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No data available in table"
            },
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button id='cancelBooking' class='ui fluid red button cancelBooking'>Cancel</button><button id='updateBooking' class='ui fluid teal button updateBooking'>Update</button>"
            } ],
            "ajax": {
                "url": Routing.generate('generate_report'),
                "type": "POST",
                "processing":true,
                "data": {
                    startDate: postdata.startDate,
                    endDate: postdata.endDate,
                    companies: postdata.companies,
                    status : postdata.status
                },
                'language': {
                    'loadingRecords': '&nbsp;',
                    'processing': '<div class="ui text loader">Loading</div>'
                },
                success:function(data){
                    //save in global dictionary
                    csvData = data;

                    //reset totalNumOfDays
                    totalNumOfDays =0;

                    //reset totalNumOfSales
                    totalNumOfSales=0;

                    if (data.length> 0){
                        data.map(res => {
                            //format datetime for fromDate
                            let statusDom;

                            if(res.status === 'Received'){
                                statusDom = `<div class="ui" data-position="top left" data-tooltip="Customer haven't yet, but already generate quotation."><a class="ui yellow label">${res.status}</a></div>`;
                            }else if(res.status === 'Confirmed'){
                                statusDom = `<div class="ui" data-position="top left" data-tooltip="Customer already make payment."><a class="ui green label">${res.status}</a></div>`;
                            }else {
                                statusDom = `<div class="ui" data-position="top left" data-tooltip="Partner or admin cancel the booking"><a class="ui red label">${res.status}</a></div>`;
                            }

                            let startDate = moment(res.fromDate);
                            let endDate   = moment(res.toDate);

                            let dateDiff = endDate.diff(startDate,'days');
                            totalNumOfDays  = totalNumOfDays+dateDiff;

                            let buttons    = `<button class="ui fluid red button" value="${res.refId}" onclick="showDeleteModal()">Delete</button> <br/>
                                             `;
                            totalNumOfSales = totalNumOfSales +  res.totalAmt;

                        //<button class="ui fluid teal button"  value="${res.refId}">Update</button>

                            salesTable.row.add([
                                `${res.customer.firstName} ${res.customer.lastName}`,
                                res.company.name,
                                res.refId,
                                statusDom,
                                res.fromDate,
                                res.toDate,
                                dateDiff,
                                res.vehicleType,
                                res.purpose,
                                res.totalAmt,
                                res.coverAmt
                            ]).draw(false);
                        })


                        $("#totalNumOfDays").html(totalNumOfDays);
                        $("#totalNumOfSales").html(totalNumOfSales.toFixed(2));
                    } else {
                        $(".dataTables_empty").css('text-align','center');
                        $(".dataTables_empty").html('No data available in table');
                        $("#totalNumOfDays").html(0);
                        $("#totalNumOfSales").html(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } );

    //cancel booking
    $('#salesTable tbody').on( 'click', '.cancelBooking', function () {
        let data = salesTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        let refId   = data[ 2 ];

        $(".refId").html(refId);

        $('.coupled.modal').modal({
                allowMultiple: false
            });

        $('.first.modal').modal({
            'onApprove' : function (event) {

               // salesTable.ajax.reload();

                let reason = $("#deleteReason").val();

                if (reason ==="") {
                    $("#deleteForm>div").addClass('error');
                    $("#deleteForm").next().removeClass('hide');

                    //still open
                    $('.first.modal').modal('show');
                    return false;

                }


                //cancel booking via api
                cancelBooking(refId,reason).then(response => {

                    if (response.status === 400){
                        $("#secondModelHeader").html("Error");
                        $("#secondModelContent").html(response.data);

                    }
                    if (response.status ===201) {
                        $("#secondModelHeader").html("Success");
                        $("#secondModelContent").html(response.data.cancelMessage);
                    }

                    $('.second.modal').modal({
                        'onApprove': function (){
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }).modal('show');
                });



            }
        }).modal('show')


    } );

    $('#salesTable tbody').on( 'click', '.updateBooking', function () {
        let data = salesTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        let refId   = data[ 2 ];

        let updateBooking  =  Routing.generate('update_booking');
        window.location.href = `${updateBooking}/${refId}`;

    } );


    return salesTable
}
```

How can I make my "Cancel" and "Update" Button able to click after ajax call and loaded into datatable?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
$('#salesTable tbody').on( 'click', '#cancelBooking', function () {
```

here you are using `#cancelBooking` which is an `id` and id must be unique in a web page, and same happens for:

```
$('#salesTable tbody').on( 'click', '#updateBooking', function () {
```

change these two into class and try again.

Comment: It is the same error, I have edited my code above question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I just simply solve by storing `let salesTable;`  globally and change the `draw(false)` to `draw()` and seems like I can click the button after ajax reload. Below is my fixed

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
import 'semantic-ui-sass';
import 'datatables.net-se';
import {initReportDateTime, generateCSV} from "./helper";
import moment from 'moment';

//routing
const routes = require('../../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js';
import {cancelBooking} from "../utility/api";

Routing.setRoutingData(routes);


//dictionary variable for later use
let csvData ;
let totalNumOfDays =0;
let totalNumOfSales =0;
let salesTable;

$(document).ready(function(){

    let postData = {
        startDate: null,
        endDate  : null,
        companies: null
    }

    drawTable(postData);

    initReportDateTime("#reportDateRange");

    $("#downloadCsv").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (csvData !== null && csvData !==''){
            generateCSV(csvData,"Sales_Report",totalNumOfSales.toFixed(2),totalNumOfDays);
        }
    });

    $("#report_form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let dateRange = $("#reportDateRange").val();
        let companies = $("#report_company").val();
        let status = $("#report_status").val();
        let splitDate = dateRange.split(" ");

        let startDate   = splitDate[0];
        let endDate     = splitDate[2];

        postData = {
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate  : endDate,
            companies: companies,
            status   : status
        }

        $('#salesTable').DataTable().destroy();


        //redraw table
        drawTable(postData);
    })

    $("#deleteReason").on('keypress',function () {
        ( $(this).val()  !== '') ?
            $(this).parent().removeClass('error') : null;

    })
});

export default function drawTable(postdata){
         salesTable =$('#salesTable').DataTable( {
            "paging":   true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info":     false,
            "responsive": true,
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No data available in table"
            },
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -1,
               // "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button id='cancelBooking' class='ui fluid red button cancelBooking'>Cancel</button><button id='updateBooking' class='ui fluid teal button updateBooking'>Update</button>"
            } ],
            "ajax": {
                "url": Routing.generate('generate_report'),
                "type": "POST",
                "processing":true,
                "data": {
                    startDate: postdata.startDate,
                    endDate: postdata.endDate,
                    companies: postdata.companies,
                    status : postdata.status
                },
                'language': {
                    'loadingRecords': '&nbsp;',
                    'processing': '<div class="ui text loader">Loading</div>'
                },
                success:function(data){
                    //save in global dictionary
                    csvData = data;

                    //reset totalNumOfDays
                    totalNumOfDays =0;

                    //reset totalNumOfSales
                    totalNumOfSales=0;

                    if (data.length> 0){
                        data.map(res => {
                            //format datetime for fromDate
                            let statusDom;

                            if(res.status === 'Received'){
                                statusDom = `<div class="ui" data-position="top left" data-tooltip="Customer haven't yet, but already generate quotation."><a class="ui yellow label">${res.status}</a></div>`;
                            }else if(res.status === 'Confirmed'){
                                statusDom = `<div class="ui" data-position="top left" data-tooltip="Customer already make payment."><a class="ui green label">${res.status}</a></div>`;
                            }else {
                                statusDom = `<div class="ui" data-position="top left" data-tooltip="Partner or admin cancel the booking"><a class="ui red label">${res.status}</a></div>`;
                            }

                            let startDate = moment(res.fromDate);
                            let endDate   = moment(res.toDate);

                            let dateDiff = endDate.diff(startDate,'days');
                            totalNumOfDays  = totalNumOfDays+dateDiff;

                            let buttons    = `<button class="ui fluid red button" value="${res.refId}" onclick="showDeleteModal()">Delete</button> <br/>
                                             `;
                            totalNumOfSales = totalNumOfSales +  res.totalAmt;

                        //<button class="ui fluid teal button"  value="${res.refId}">Update</button>

                            salesTable.row.add([
                                `${res.customer.firstName} ${res.customer.lastName}`,
                                res.company.name,
                                res.refId,
                                statusDom,
                                res.fromDate,
                                res.toDate,
                                dateDiff,
                                res.vehicleType,
                                res.purpose,
                                res.totalAmt,
                                res.coverAmt
                            ]).draw();
                        })


                        $("#totalNumOfDays").html(totalNumOfDays);
                        $("#totalNumOfSales").html(totalNumOfSales.toFixed(2));
                    } else {
                        $(".dataTables_empty").css('text-align','center');
                        $(".dataTables_empty").html('No data available in table');
                        $("#totalNumOfDays").html(0);
                        $("#totalNumOfSales").html(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } );

    //cancel booking
    $('#salesTable tbody').on( 'click', '.cancelBooking', function () {
        let data = salesTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        let refId   = data[ 2 ];

        $(".refId").html(refId);

        $('.coupled.modal').modal({
                allowMultiple: false
            });

        $('.first.modal').modal({
            'onApprove' : function (event) {

               // salesTable.ajax.reload();

                let reason = $("#deleteReason").val();

                if (reason ==="") {
                    $("#deleteForm>div").addClass('error');
                    $("#deleteForm").next().removeClass('hide');

                    //still open
                    $('.first.modal').modal('show');
                    return false;

                }


                //cancel booking via api
                cancelBooking(refId,reason).then(response => {

                    if (response.status === 400){
                        $("#secondModelHeader").html("Error");
                        $("#secondModelContent").html(response.data);

                    }
                    if (response.status ===201) {
                        $("#secondModelHeader").html("Success");
                        $("#secondModelContent").html(response.data.cancelMessage);
                    }

                    $('.second.modal').modal({
                        'onApprove': function (){
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }).modal('show');
                });



            }
        }).modal('show')


    } );

    $('#salesTable tbody').on( 'click', '.updateBooking', function () {
        let data = salesTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        let refId   = data[ 2 ];

        let updateBooking  =  Routing.generate('update_booking');
        window.location.href = `${updateBooking}/${refId}`;

    } );


    return salesTable
}
```